# Assigning probabilities to processes, when you know which probabilities exist but not which one belongs to which process

Tags: bayesian, ranking

I have multiple stochastic processes that can have 2 different realisations. I think of them as coins that can take the values heads or tails. For the example I assume that there are 3 coins. I know the 3 probabilities of showing heads that these coins have, but I don't know which belongs to which coin. For example I know that the probabilities are 60%, 50%, and 40% and each occurs exactly once i.e. if Coin A has a probability of 60% for heads, Coin B and C cannot have 60%.

I observe realisations for each coin over multiple rounds. With 3 coins there are  3! = 6 different ways the probabilities could be assigned to the coins. For each of these 6 possibilities I want to know probability that it is the true one given the data on the realisations of the 3 coins that I have. For example I want a result like with 20% probability Coin A has 60% probability of  heads, Coin B has 50% and Coin C has 40% and with 15% Probability Coin A has 50% probability of  heads, Coin B has 60% and Coin C has 40% and so on.

How can I calculate these probabilities?

Comment: interesting question. It's not hard to come up with the _most likely_ ordering, but deriving probabilities seems harder. Actually, with a computer, it's not so hard I think

Comment: The nature of your situation is unclear: I cannot see the sense in which "2 different realizations," "3 coins," and "multiple rounds" all describe the same experiment.  Could you perhaps display and explain a small example?

Comment: To clarify: the two different possible realisations are heads or tails if we thing of the processes as coins. I have 3 biased coins that I flip at the same time and observe the results. After I have observed the results I flip all 3 coins again and observe the results. This is what I mean by multiple rounds. So if I have 4 rounds and 3 coins for example that would mean that I flip each of the 3 coins 4 times and observe heads or tails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to iterate over all possible permutations, compute the posterior probability (likelihood * prior), and then normalize.

Here's a Python program to compute the posterior probabilities:

```
from math import factorial
from itertools import permutations

# these are our fixed probabilities
P = [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]

# need a prior
PRIOR = 1.0/3.0

# here's the observed data: 5 "rounds", and the number of successes of each coin.
observed_data = (5, (3,2,1))


# some helper functions
def C(n, r):
    return factorial(n) / factorial(r) / factorial(n-r)


def likelihood(observed_data, permutation):
    """
    permutation is a permutation of (0,1,2)

    """

    N, successes = observed_data
    prob = 1.0
    for observed_i, proposed_i in enumerate(permutation):
        p = P[proposed_i]
        r = successes[observed_i]
        prob *= C(N, r) * p**r * (1 - p)**(N - r)
    return prob 


def unnormalized_posterior_probability(observed_data, permutation):
    """
    observed_data is a tuple, first element is the number of rounds
    the second element is a list representing the count of successes
    ex: (5, [2, 0, 3])

    """
    return likelihood(observed_data, permutation) * PRIOR 

# compute the posterior probabilities
running_sum = 0
posterior_probabilities = {}

for possible_order in permutations((0,1,2)):
    posterior_probabilities[possible_order] = unnormalized_posterior_probability(observed_data, possible_order)
    running_sum += posterior_probabilities[possible_order]

for possible_order in permutations((0,1,2)):
    posterior_probabilities[possible_order] = posterior_probabilities[possible_order] / running_sum
```

The output looks like:

```
{(0, 1, 2): 0.063,
 (0, 2, 1): 0.094,
 (1, 0, 2): 0.094,
 (1, 2, 0): 0.213,
 (2, 0, 1): 0.213,
 (2, 1, 0): 0.320}
```

Which suggests that `(2, 1, 0)` is the most probable order (which makes sense, given `P` and the observed data.

Comment: Thank you for the code, this is an improvement over my own approach.I think it is still not the ideal solution because it does not use all information. The issue I see is that in the "def likelihood:"  part you get the likelihood of a permutation by calculating individual likelihoods for each of the 3 coins and then multiply them. I think that relies on a independence assumption that we can't make. When we look at the data and ask how likely is it that a coin with 0.4 probability generated the data we need to account for the fact otherwise it must have been one with 0.5 or 0.6 probability.

Comment: > we need to account for the fact otherwise it must have been one with 0.5 or 0.6 probability.
hm, that part is done in the normalization in the `for` loops, no?

Comment: My intuition is that taking the fact that the only possible probabilities for the coins are 0.4,0.5 and 0.6 into account in the step where you calculate the probability of a permutation is not necessarily the same as calculating the probabilities for each coin individually, multiply them up and then normalise later. I might be wrong about this but i think with Bayesian updating their should be a way to do this without normalising.

Comment: My interpretation: the information is being used, but it's implicit. Going back to Bayes: $P(A=a|B=b) = P(B=b | A=a) P(A=a) / P(B=b)$ - note that our likelihood term, $P(B=b | A=a)$ we are using that $A=a$, and implicitly that $A \ne a', A \ne a''$, etc. So we are using the information in this sense.Similarly, in our example, in $P(B=b)$ we are using that there are only three possibilities for $A$, again implicitly: $P(B=b) = P(B=b | A=a) P(A=a) + P(B=b | A=a') P(A=a') + P(B=b | A=a'') P(A=a'')$.